# why my radcombobox is empty after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik

I have a radcombobox,I want get checked items and save it in database but when i click save button,page is load again and my radcombobox become empty and then all of my checked items disappear.please help me,how can keep ckeckeditems?

Comment: Can you provide some code showing how `RadComboBox` is defined on your page?

Comment: My guess is you're creating or binding them in page_load without seeing if the request is a postback or not.  Post your `Page_Load` method and it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As D Stanley mentioned in the comments, you're probably not checking for a postback when populating your dropdown.

This is the general approach you need to use in your code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateTheDropdown();
    }
}

private void PopulateTheDropdown()
{
    // Populate / databind your dropdown here
}
```

This will ensure your dropdown is not rebound when a postback occurs so you don't lose the selected value(s).

Comment: thanks,but it does'nt work.i find a solution for that.I bind datasource of radcombobox in (init) event and then in postback is no empty

Answer (score 0):

If you have autopostback activated you must save the selected value separately. Try to explicitly disable and check the value when the event fires:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxControl" AutoPostBack="false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBoxControl_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select something"></telerik:RadComboBox>

protected void RadComboBoxControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Only test
  var seleccionado = RadComboBoxControl.Items.FindItemByText(e.Text);
}
```

Check if you have assigned DataSource of the control in other parts of the code

```
RadComboBoxControl.DataSource = ...
RadComboBoxControl.DataBind();
```

This will also lose the selected element